# android lifecycler work in debug only and not working in rellease

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have used lifecycle observer for animating motionlayout based on keyboard shown/hidden it works as expected in debug but when I generate release it doesn't work and lifecycle methods not triggered

My lifecycle observer base class

```
enter code here
public interface LifecycleObserver extends androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
public void onResume();

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
public void onCreate();

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
public  void onPause();
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
public  void onDestroy();
```

}

class that uses lifecycle observer 
    public abstract class KeyboardUtils implements

```
LifecycleObserver,ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        private BaseActivity activity;
public int defaulThreeshold = -1;
private boolean keyboardListenersAttached = false;
private ViewGroup rootLayout;
private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener keyboardLayoutListener = this;
public KeyboardUtils(BaseActivity activity) {
    Log.e("KeyboardUtils","KeyboardUtils constructor");
    this.activity = activity;
    activity.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
}

public abstract void onShowKeyboard(int keyboardHeight);
public abstract void onHideKeyboard();
public int heightDiff;
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    if (defaulThreeshold == -1)
        defaulThreeshold = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - rootLayout.getHeight();
    heightDiff = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - rootLayout.getHeight();
    int contentViewTop = activity.getWindow().findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();

    LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(activity);

    if(heightDiff <= defaulThreeshold + contentViewTop){
        onHideKeyboard();

        Intent intent = new Intent("KeyboardWillHide");
        broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    } else {
        int keyboardHeight = heightDiff - contentViewTop;
        onShowKeyboard(keyboardHeight);

        Intent intent = new Intent("KeyboardWillShow");
        intent.putExtra("KeyboardHeight", keyboardHeight);
        broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
public static boolean hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (inputMethodManager.isActive()) {
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null&&inputMethodManager.isAcceptingText()) {
            return inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
         }
    }
    return false;
}
protected void attachKeyboardListeners() {
    Log.e("KeyboardUtils","attachKeyboardListeners");
    if (keyboardListenersAttached) {
        return;
    }

    rootLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.activity_root);
    rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(keyboardLayoutListener);
    keyboardListenersAttached = true;
}
@Override
public void onResume() {

    Log.e("KeyboardUtils","onResume");
    attachKeyboardListeners();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.e("KeyboardUtils","onPause");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e("KeyboardUtils","onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (keyboardListenersAttached) {
        rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(keyboardLayoutListener);
    }
        activity.getLifecycle().removeObserver(this);

}
}
```